# Proof of Limit using epsilon and N0

Tags: calculus

Prove (using $\varepsilon$ and $N_0$) that 
$$\lim\limits_{ n \to \infty}\frac{24n+17}{8n-15}=3$$
I've found $\frac{1}{8}{(\frac{62}{\varepsilon}+15)} < n$

Comment: I hope I edited it correctly.

Comment: Then you're done: make $N_0$ be the ceiling of that (or the ceiling +1, if your definition uses $n \geq N_0$ rather than $n>N_0$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given, and choose $N_0>\frac{8}{\epsilon}+2$.

If $n\ge N_0\;,$ then $\displaystyle n>\frac{8}{\epsilon}+2\implies n-2>\frac{8}{\epsilon}\implies\frac{1}{n-2}<\frac{\epsilon}{8}\implies\frac{8}{n-2}<\epsilon$

$\hspace{.75 in}\displaystyle\implies\left|\frac{24n+17}{8n-15}-3\right|=\left|\frac{62}{8n-15}\right|=\frac{62}{8n-15}<\frac{64}{8n-16}=\frac{8}{n-2}<\epsilon$

Comment: You fed this person an answer, and now they are back 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1473044/some-linear-algebra-questions

Comment: @LieAlgebra I try to avoid answering homework questions when work is not shown, but 1) the question included the correct inequality for n and 2) fleablood had already answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

So you are done really.

For $\epsilon$ > 0.  Let $N_0 >\frac{1}{8}{(\frac{62}{\varepsilon}+15)} $.  If $n > N_0$, then $|3 -   \frac{24n+17}{8n-15}| = |\frac{3(8n - 15) - (24n + 17) = -62}{8n - 15} | = |\frac{62}{8n - 15}| < |\frac{62}{8(\frac{1}{8}{(\frac{62}{\varepsilon}+15)}) - 15}  | = |\frac{62}{\frac{62}{\varepsilon}}   | =  \varepsilon$.  This is true for any choice of $\epsilon$, so $\lim\limits_{ n \to \infty}\frac{24n+17}{8n-15}=3$

======

I've never is any student or professor go through this tedium but I've often wondered if it would help to get a grasp on this using real numbers.

If I want to find get all  $\frac{24n+17}{8n-15}$ within 1/10 distance from 3, I have to chose n > 635/8 = 79.375. If n >= 80 then |3 -$\frac{24n+17}{8n-15}$| = |(24n - 45 - 24n -17)/(8n -15)| = |-62/(8n-15)| <= |-62/(8*80 -15)| = |62/625| < 1/10.

Comment: You fed this person an answer, and now they are back http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1473044/some-linear-algebra-questions